# Again PendigIntent in notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications, android-pendingintent

I'm notifying user about some events (in my case SMS receiving) and hanging PendingIntent like:

```
intent = new Intent(context, ConversationActivity.class);
intent.setAction(Constants.ACTION_SMS_RECEIVED);
intent.putExtra(MessageDAO.CONVERSATION_ID, message.getConversationId());
intent.putExtra(MessageDAO._ID, message.getId());
intent.putExtra(MessageDAO.ADDRESS, message.getAddress());
contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT );
```

My purpose is to start new `ConversationActivity` if there's no one, either just reuse old one (refreshing its content). But in fact my `PendingIntent` just use old one not refreshing it's content. I have checked that old extras still send to my `ConversationActivity`

What is the problem? I'm really stuck with it and can't understand what to do...

**Update**

I'm extracting extras in target `ConversationActivity.onCreate()` like:

```
Bundle bundle=this.getIntent().getExtras();
    if(bundle!=null) {
        conversationId=bundle.getString(MessageDAO.CONVERSATION_ID);
        address=bundle.getString(MessageDAO.ADDRESS);
    }
```

Comment: What is the state of the "old" activity when the new `Intent` is sent to it? Where (in what method) and how are you checking the extras? Show the code you use to extract/examine the extras.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reuse an existing activity, you need to do the following. When creating the notification, add this:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

Then you will need to override `onNewIntent()` in `ConversationActivity`. This will be called (instead of `onCreate()` if the user clicks on a notification and there is already an active `ConversationActivity`. You will need to extract the "extras" from the `Intent` in `onNewIntent()` and replace the content with this new data.